# Efficiently Import SAS into R looping with read_sas, columns to import differ by file

Tags: r, import, sas

Trying to use `read_sas` to import some SAS files in one folder into R, with the file name meeting the pattern "medpar20XX", (XX = 00,01,....,16).
Also, a specific list of columns is needed. I used a for loop but only the last SAS data file (according to the loop increment indicator) was imported successfully, and all the resulted R data frames are this last data file.

Below is code to get the list of files in the folder that meet the file name pattern

```r
patt = "medpar[0-9]{4}[[:punct:]]sas7bdat"
file_list <- list.files(path="E:/Data/Bell_Disasters",pattern = patt)
```

[The file_list is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdzAY.png)

The code to read a single file with path and file name spelled out:

```
medpar2000 <- read_sas("E:/Data/Bell_Disasters/medpar2000.sas7bdat", cols_only = c("HIC","PRVNUMGRP","SSLSSNF","sadmsndt","sdschrgdt"))
```

The SAS file was imported successfully.

Below is the for loop to read in the SAS data files. For year between 2000 -2002 the columns needed are the same (specified in `cols_only=c("HIC","PRVNUMGRP","SSLSSNF","sadmsndt","sdschrgdt")`) , but for other years, the columns are different. When year is between 2003 and 2006, `cols_only = c('BENE_ID','PRVSTATE','PRVNUM3','PRVDRSRL','SSLSSNF','ADMSNDT','DSCHRGDT')`.
For year between 2007 and 2012, `cols_only = c('bene_id', 'MEDPAR_ID', 'PRVDR_NUM', 'SS_LS_SNF_IND_CD', 'ADMSN_DT', 'DSCHRG_DT')`.

Below is the code I tested on year between 2000 and 2002 only, and I update the logic on year to `if', instead of`for` loop:

```r
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
{
  # retrieve the year number in the sas file name
  year <-regmatches(file_list[i],regexpr('[0-9]{4}',file_list[i]))
  if (year %in% c('2000','2001','2002')) {
    # read in SAS data set
    temp_data <- read_sas(file.path('E:/Data/Bell_Disasters',file_list[i]), cols_only = c("HIC","PRVNUMGRP","SSLSSNF","sadmsndt","sdschrgdt"))
    # rename data set
    assign(paste('medpar',year,sep =''),temp_data)
  }
 else if (year %in% c('2003','2004','2005','2006') {

  # read in SAS data set
    temp_data <- read_sas(file.path('E:/Data/Bell_Disasters',file_list[i]), cols_only=c('BENE_ID','PRVSTATE','PRVNUM3','PRVDRSRL','SSLSSNF','ADMSNDT','DSCHRGDT')
    # rename data set
    assign(paste('medpar',year,sep =''),temp_data)
}

}
```

The process is extremely slow. When I force stop, I see some files are indeed imported successfully into R. Is there a way to make this process more efficient?

Comment: Do you have code that reads a single file directly?

Comment: Per `r` tag (hover to see): *please specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls* such as `read_sas`.

Comment: By the way, re-consider using `assign` to save potentially many similar structured data frames to flood global environment. Instead use **one** list of many data frames. As @Gregor advises [Don't ever create d1 d2 d3, ..., dn in the first place. Create a list d with n elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451)

Comment: Why are you looping over file names and also looping over years?  Isn't the year part of the filename?

Comment: @Tom Maybe looping over years is a bad idea, but I need a check on the year value   because the `cols_only` depend on the year.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `lapply` to build a list of named data frames. Also, wrap `read_sas` in `tryCatch` so on error it returns an empty data frame of similar columns for those problematic one or more files. From final output, investigate the zero-row data frames to find out why their imports failed.

```
setwd("E:/Data/Bell_Disasters")
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "medpar[0-9]{4}[[:punct:]]sas7bdat")

# BUILD LIST OF DATA FRAMES
medpar_list <- lapply(file_list, function(f) {    
   tryCatch(read_sas(f, cols_only = c("HIC", "PRVNUMGRP", "SSLSSNF", 
                                      "sadmsndt", "sdschrgdt")),
            error = function(e) data.frame(HIC=NA, PRVNUMGRP=NA, SSLSSNF=NA, 
                                           sadmsndt=NA, sdschrgdt=NA)
           )                
})

# NAME LIST OF DATA FRAMES
names(medpar_list) <- gsub(".sas7bdat", "", file_list)

# DISPLAY DATA FRAMES
head(medpar_list$medpar2000)
head(medpar_list$medpar2001)
head(medpar_list$medpar2002)
...
```

Comment: How do I incorporate the requirement that columns to import differ by year. i.e. for year between 2000 and 2002, `cols_only = c("HIC","PRVNUMGRP","SSLSSNF","sadmsndt","sdschrgdt")`, but when year is between 2003 and 2006, `cols_only = c('BENE_ID','PRVSTATE','PRVNUM3','PRVDRSRL','SSLSSNF','ADMSNDT','DSCHRGDT')`

Answer (score 0):

**You have a logic error**. For each file you are looping though 2000, 2001 and 2002 and therefore at the end, all three data frames `medpar2000` to `medpar2002` will contain the same data corresponding to the last SAS dataset that is being read. The following code works fine as you expect to.

```
library(haven)

patt = "medpar[0-9]{4}[[:punct:]]sas7bdat"
file_list <- list.files(path="E:/Data/Bell_Disasters",pattern = patt)

for (i in 1:length(file_list))
{
  # retrieve the year number in the sas file name
  year <-regmatches(file_list[i],regexpr('[0-9]{4}',file_list[i]))

  # read in SAS data set
  temp_data <- read_sas(file.path('E:/Data/Bell_Disasters',file_list[i]), cols_only = c("HIC","PRVNUMGRP","SSLSSNF","sadmsndt","sdschrgdt"))
  # rename data set
  assign(paste('medpar',year,sep =''),temp_data)
}
```